# Gulp-protractor keep saying "Spec patterns did not match any files"

Tags: angularjs, gulp, protractor, gulp-protractor

I'm trying to run my end to end tests written with protractor and jasmine. It works perfectly when I call `protractor protractor.config.js` directly.

However, when I use gulp-protractor, I keep getting the "Spec patterns did not match any files" error and the tests do not run.

This is my protractor runner gulp task:

```
gulp.task('protractor-run', function (done) {
    return gulp.src(["./e2e-tests/**/*-spec.js"])
        .pipe(protractor({
            configFile: "./config/protractor-config.js",
            args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000']
        }))
        .on('error', function(e) { throw e })
});
```

and this is the error:

```
WARNING - pattern C:\path\to\app\e2e-tests\login\login-spec.js did not math any files.
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
C:\path\to\app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                   throw e;
                   ^

Error: Spec patterns did not match any files.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same issue, asked here on SO like 2 seconds ago

Comment: Have the same issue after updating to latest protractor 2.3.0. It worked before the update (2.2.0).

Comment: Also see protractor [issue #2551](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2551)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working. By providing an empty readable stream. Then you specify your spec files in the config file instead.

```
var protractor = require('gulp-protractor').protractor;

gulp.task('protractor', ['webdriverUpdate'],function(){
      return gulp.src([])
          .pipe(protractor({
            configFile: __dirname + '/protractor.conf.js'
          }));
});
```

also don't forget the webdriverUpdate

```
var webdriverUpdate = require('gulp-protractor').webdriver_update;

gulp.task('webdriverUpdate', webdriverUpdate );
```

and in the config file this:

```
seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar',
```

With this I stopped getting the error.

**Update**

The [issue #2551](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2551) is closed and fixed since 2.5.0

Comment: I have about the same issue. The main problem for me is that my path has a space in it "Documents\Visual Studio 2013\..." and it won't get past the Visual bit because of the space in it. The __dirname doesn't seem to do the trick for me. But it's in the right direction though. I need to figure out a way to make it use my whole directory path

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in a gulpfile that launches protractor tests by putting a file path into the parameter of gulp.src(['file_path_goes_here']).  The task I was trying to run had no file path between the brackets, and was throwing the error.

```
gulp.task('works', 'Run some tests', function() {
  gulp.src(['path/to/test.spec.js'])
    .pipe(protractor({
      configFile: __dirname + '/../test/protractor.conf.js',
      args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://localhost:9099']
    }))
});

gulp.task('error', 'Run feature tests locally', function() {
  gulp.src([''])
    .pipe(protractor({
      configFile: __dirname + '/../test/protractor_local.conf.js',
      args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://localhost:9099']
    }))
});
```